# Texto estranho aparecendo em página depois de salvar um arquivo

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net

Estou criando um editor de texto em C#, mas quando salvei um arquivo `.html`, na pagina apareceu esse erro

[image: SS]

Código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace onedev
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string language; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void hTMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            language = "HTML";
            codding.Text += "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head><title>Hello world</title></head> <body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";
        }

        private void htmlToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void salvarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (language == "HTML")
            {
                SaveFileDialog saveHtml = new SaveFileDialog();
                saveHtml.DefaultExt = "*.html";
                saveHtml.Filter = "HTML|*.html";

                if (saveHtml.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
                   saveHtml.FileName.Length > 0)
                {
                    codding.SaveFile(saveHtml.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho difícil alguém te ajudar sem olhar nenhum código, mas como não entendo de C# ...

Comment: Só com esse trecho ainda parece ser complicado oferecer alguma solução. Precisamos de mais informações, trechos mais relevantes. Não esqueça que o correto é [edit] a pergunta para colocar o novo trecho.

Comment: codigo editado.

Comment: por acaso "codding" é editor de texto RTF do Windows Forms?